# BitmapImage CreateOptions in code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In XAML you can create a `BitmapImage` with `CreateOptions` set as follows

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation, IgnoreImageCache"/>
```

How to specify those `CreateOptions` in C# programatically?

`BitmapImage bimg = new BitmapImage(){CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation ???}`, how to set IgnoreImageCache?

Comment: My guess is you need to do a bit-wise OR using `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has confirmed my original guess.

> This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values.

To do this, you need the following:

```
BitmapImage bimg = new BitmapImage();                        
bimg.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation 
                     | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache
```

Note: The only reason I did not use object initialization syntax was to prevent horizontal scrolling.